# Dynamic array with malloc doesn't work but fixed size does - C

Tags: c, dynamic, segmentation-fault, malloc, coredump

Why does a fixed array work but when I try to make it dynamic with malloc it gives a segmentation fault? I've tried all sorts of values besides *10. This is just using a small file. I need this to work with a dictionary of 90,000 words.

```
FILE *fp;
long lSize;
//char buffer[100];
char *buffer=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
int i = 0;

fp = fopen ( "cats.txt" , "rb" );
if( !fp ) perror("cats.txt"),exit(1);

wordTree = makeEmptyTree();

while( fscanf(fp, "%s", &buffer) != EOF )
{
    addStringToTree(wordTree, buffer);
    //printf("%s\n", words[i]);
}

fclose(fp);
//free(buffer);
```

I can include addStringToTree as well if needed.

### Edit 1

Thanks guys that fixed it. Unfortunately I couldn't get the 90,000 words text file to work, still getting the seg fault error.

Comment: Regarding the edit. Make buffer large enough. If problem still persists, make sure everything is right with `wordTree`. Try to use a debugger such as gdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
char *buffer=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```

to

```
char *buffer=malloc(100);
```

and

```
while( fscanf(fp, "%s", &buffer) != EOF )
```

to

```
while( fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer) != EOF )
```

then try again.

1. `sizeof(char)` always returns 1, and the size of `buffer` should be 100 (because in static case its 100);
2. `buffer` already a pointer to `char`, `&` before it is not necessary and will give the address of pointer instead of address pointed to by `buffer`. (And this is probably the cause of segment fault.)

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer) //remove the ampersand
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing pointer-to-a-pointer in fscanf. Just have buffer in fscanf. In 'char buffer[]' case, &buffer and buffer are equivalent. Hence no seg-fault in that case.

Comment: They are not equivalent, but on common implementations it works anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the types of your fixed array and dynamically allocated array are different:

```
char buffer[100];
```

vs.

```
char* buffer
```

Malloc returns the address location of your dynamically allocated memory, so you don't need to prefix it with '&'. So simply use this:

```
while( fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer) != EOF )
{
    .....
```